# How to start the android emulator without blocking the build in jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation

I'm trying to start the emulator, on a mac(sierra) jenkins slave like this:
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_25 -wipe-data

And the build hangs. It starts the emulator, but it does not proceed with the build.

I guess I need to start it as a background process, which should be something like this:
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_25 -wipe-data $

but I get an error:
invalid command-line parameter: $.

What would be the correct way of starting the emulator without blocking the build?

edit: I would like to solve this without installing the android emulator plugin(I have no rights, or permission to install it)